# Yarn Install Error: Arguments: -c ./node_modules/.bin/typings install

Tags: npm-install, yarnpkg

When trying to run yarn install I am getting:

```
Jasons-MacBook-Pro: jasonbiondo$ yarn install
yarn install v0.21.3
[1/4] :mag:  Resolving packages...
[2/4] :truck:  Fetching packages...
[3/4] :link:  Linking dependencies...
[4/4] :page_with_curl:  Building fresh packages...
[1/6] ⠂ aurelia-infinite-scroll
[2/6] ⠂ fsevents
[3/6] ⠂ gifsicle
[4/6] ⠂ mozjpeg
error /Users/jasonbiondo/Sites/mysite-app/node_modules/aurelia-infinite-scroll: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: sh
Arguments: -c ./node_modules/.bin/typings install
Directory: /Users/jasonbiondo/Sites/mysite-app/node_modules/aurelia-infinite-scroll
Output:
sh: ./node_modules/.bin/typings: No such file or directory
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Note: This does not throw an error with npm install.

Here is a link to a gist of my package.json:  https://gist.github.com/jasonbiondo/fac812526499c99e44c171645bee5533